# How to perform a normality test for stratified samples with different weights in R

Tags: r, sampling, survey, survival-analysis

Let's assume a stratified sampling design where some groups are over- and others underrepresented for theoretical purposes.

For all test-statistics and regression type models we can use the `survey` package in `R` to correct for the sampling design by giving each observation a weight based on its occurrence in the true population N.

However i did not find a method to check some fundamental assumptions of those models.

Let's assume the sampled data looks like this:

```
df<-data.frame(var=1:1000,
               weights=as.numeric(as.character(cut(abs(sort(rnorm(1000))),breaks=10,labels = (10:1)))))
```

We can observe, that the variable *"var"* is clearly not-normally distributed in the sample. A shapiro test confirms this:

```
shapiro.test(df$var)
```

gives

```
Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  df$var
W = 0.95481, p-value < 0.00000000000000022
```

However, the weights could change this if we e.g. compare the weighted and un-weighted histogram:

```
library('survey')
df$id<-paste("id",1:1000,sep="")
df.weights<-svydesign(id=~id,
                      weights=~weights,
                      data=df)
hist(df$var)

svyhist(~var,df.weights)
```

hence, the "true" distribution of the variable in N might be closer to normal. In case of normality in N, I would  argue that statistical methods that assume normality would be valid in a model that corrects for the survey design.

So my question is, how can I implement a normality test for a stratified sample with different weights?

Comment: i don't think anyone has implemented a `shapiro.test()` that properly accounts for the sampling design.  if you are only looking to account for the weights, use `shapiro.test( svytable( ~ var , df.weights ) )` but this technique might be oversensitive when a sample design has clusters.